# Find all distinct alternate usernames by an ip in a single query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a query that will take a `player_id`, find all distinct `ip` addresses logged for that person, and pull a list of distinct other `player_id`s that share each ip.

Example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ips` (
  `ip_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ip_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `joins` (
  `join_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`join_id`)
);
```

The ips table records every unique ip I see, a players table records each unique player (not important for this) and the joins table records each time they connect.

Doing this with two queries was my first idea, and that works and is speedy - but I'd really like to make this work with a single query. I tried a query that uses a subquery but that takes forever to complete.

What's the most efficient way to query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/133c6/1

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  joins2.player_id,
  ips.ip


FROM joins

JOIN ips
  ON ips.ip_id          = joins.ip_id

JOIN joins             AS joins2
  ON joins2.ip_id       = ips.ip_id
 AND joins2.player_id  != #player_id


WHERE joins.player_id   = #player_id
```

Comment: This works well. My sub-query was taking about 2 1/2 seconds (up to two minutes before I added indexes to the ip_id/player_id columns) but with this it took 1.81 sec. That's certainly better and is within range I feel I can work with. I'll see what else I can do to speed it up. Thanks